# Show div on hover of direct parent only

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div appear when you **only hover its direct parent div**. Right now the div will show when you hover any div of that type. See this [simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/6p4yaaws/4/) of the problem.

How can I make a `.menu` div only show when the mouse hovers directly over that div (and not it's child divs)?

```css
.widget {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}
.menu {
  background-color: #444;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}
.widget:hover > .menu {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: #eee;">
  <div class="menu">
    <p>I should ONLY be visible when you hover the big outer widget and NOT when you are hovering the small inner widget</p>
  </div>
  <div class="widget" style="left: 200px; top: 200px;">
    <div class="menu">
      <p>I should ONLY be visible when you hover the small inner widget</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible in pure css. You'd probably have to look at Javascript and listen to mouseover/enter events.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the markup, there is no way you can target the first menu item and hide it when the child `.widget` is hovered. You will need to use JS.

I you cant use JS, you will need to change your makup, there are two ways you can achieve your aim:

Put the first `.menu` after the child `.widget` so you can target it with the `.widget:hover > .widget:hover + .menu` selector when the child widget is hovered :

```css
.widget {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.widget > .widget{
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.menu {
  background-color: #444;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}
.widget:hover > .menu {
  display: flex;
}
.widget:hover > .widget:hover + .menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget">
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="menu"><p>I should ONLY be visible when you hover the small inner widget</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu"><p>I should ONLY be visible when you hover the big outer widget and NOT when you are hovering the small inner widget</p></div>
</div>
```

A second approach would be to make the child `.widget` a sibling of the first:

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
.widget {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.w1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.w2 {
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
.menu {
  background-color: #444;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}
.widget:hover > .menu {
  display: flex;
}
.widget:hover > .widget:hover + .menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="widget w1">
    <div class="menu"><p>I should ONLY be visible when you hover the big outer widget and NOT when you are hovering the small inner widget</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget w2">
    <div class="menu"><p>I should ONLY be visible when you hover the small inner widget</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*On a side note, you should try not to use inline CSS.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for this. use the `stopPropogation()` event handler. There could be a way in direct css but I am not aware of that. This is what I have used and works well

```
$("div.widget").mouseover(
        function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).children(".menu").css("display", "flex");
        }).mouseout(
        function() {
            $(this).children(".menu").css("display", "none");
        });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/6p4yaaws/5/)

Answer (score 0):

When you `hover` parent element i.e. `.widget` over-here, you want `.menu` to be visible. You can do that using `nth-child` to target specified child element.

Try as below.

```
.widget:nth-child(1):hover > .widget:nth-child(2) > .menu{
  background:orange;
  display:flex;
}
```

```css
.widget {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}
.menu {
  background-color: #444;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}
.widget:nth-child(1):hover > .widget:nth-child(2) > .menu{
  background:orange;
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;background:#eee">
  <div class="menu">
    <p>I should ONLY be visible when you hover the big outer widget and NOT when you are hovering the small inner widget</p>
  </div>
  <div class="widget" style="left: 200px; top: 200px;">
    <div class="menu">
      <p>I should ONLY be visible when you hover the small inner widget</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And if you want `.menu` to be appear when you hover over-them then you have to change it's property i.e. remove `display:none;` and set `opacity:0.01`.

```
.widget:nth-child(1) > .menu:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
.widget:nth-child(2) > .menu:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```css
.widget {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}
.menu {
  background-color: #444;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity:0.01;
}
.widget:nth-child(1) > .menu:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
.widget:nth-child(2) > .menu:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;background:#eee">
  <div class="menu">
    <p>I should ONLY be visible when you hover the big outer widget and NOT when you are hovering the small inner widget</p>
  </div>
  <div class="widget" style="left: 200px; top: 200px;">
    <div class="menu">
      <p>I should ONLY be visible when you hover the small inner widget</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in your way then you can just edit your CSS in this way.

```
.widget {

    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    position: relative;
}

.menu {
    background-color: #444;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}

.widget:hover > .menu {
    display: flex;
}
.widget:hover > .widget > .menu{
  display: block;
}
```